# How to use centeredScaling with any fabric.js object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am able to draw and add text to my fabric.js canvas. I've set `centeredScaling: true` for text objects but I'd like them to be applied to all objects or rather any selected objects.

What can I use to initialize this for my entire canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `centeredScaling: true` to [canvas object](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#centeredScaling), to change for all object.

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',{
  backgroundColor:'white',
  centeredScaling: true
 });
```